# Problem with saving figures using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pycharm

Can't save more than 57 figures using matplotlib.pyplot.savefig using a loop.
Piece of my code:

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.pie([views, calls, shows])
    ax.set_title(name_deal)
    ax.legend([f'Views: {views}', f'Calls: {calls}', f'Shows: {shows}'], loc='lower left')
    plt.savefig(f'C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/diagramm/({id_deal}) {name_deal}.png', dpi=100)
    plt.close(fig)
```

When saving 57 figure I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\diagramm\main.py", line 34, in <module>
    plt.savefig(f'C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/diagramm/({id_deal}) {name_deal}.jpeg', dpi=100)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\diagramm\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 979, in savefig
    res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\diagramm\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 3046, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\diagramm\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2319, in print_figure
    result = print_method(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\diagramm\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1648, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\diagramm\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py", line 415, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\diagramm\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 583, in print_jpg
    return (Image.fromarray(np.asarray(self.buffer_rgba())[..., :3])
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\diagramm\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2297, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/diagramm/(13475) file_name_ghjjt.png'
```

Comment: I don't think your problem is related to matplotlib. The error states there is a problem with the file or directory you are trying to access.

Comment: there is no `57` limit on the number of figures. This is an error with `No such file or directory`.